# Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I am getting " Could not find a part of the path" error while copying a file from server to local machine. here is my code sample:

```
 try
            {
                string serverfile = @"E:\installer.msi";
                string localFile = Path.GetTempPath();
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(serverfile);
                fileInfo.CopyTo(localFile);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;

            }
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Path.GetTempPath
```

is returning you folder path. you need to specify file path as well. You can do it like this

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string serverfile = @"E:\installer.msi";
string path = Path.Combine(tempPath, Path.GetFileName(serverfile));
File.Copy(serverfile, path); //you can use the overload to specify do you want to overwrite or not
```

Answer (score 4):

You should copy *file to file*, not file to directory:

```
...
  string serverfile = @"E:\installer.msi";
  string localFile = Path.GetTempPath();
  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(serverfile);

  // Copy to localFile (which is TempPath) + installer.msi
  fileInfo.CopyTo(Path.Combine(localFile, Path.GetFileName(serverfile)));
...
```